# how to use Reactjs with Nodejs, to send html(component) in response of an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering, bigcommerce

I am working on creating a Bigcommerce app using NodeJs and Reactjs tech-stack.

In BC(Bigcommerce) API response they are expecting html that they rendered in Iframe to show the content in there app marketplace store (where the actual app runs).

> I have already created react/node app running well on EC2 instance. I
>   just want to reuse the react part (component and other routing etc)
>   here in this BC app. But as I see i need to send the HTML from
>   node(server side) app, so either I need to use server side rendering
>   engine like jade/hbs etc, or use react as SSR. If i am doing the same
>   i need to do lots of rework to use the same components and render the
>   same from server side.

Is there anyway I can use my react code directly in my BC app or somehow render the react component without doing so much of changes.

I am stuck here, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is ssr a prerequisite? You can pass reference into iframe and iframe will compile your react to html. What problems did you encounter using classic react ssr (`react-dom/server` and `hydrate`)? Are your components based on browser specific api?

Comment: @SaveliTomac thanks for your answer, No ssr is prerequisite, it just we need to send some html in the response of there (BC) API and they just render the html in iframe at there side. m just wondering to know is only react SSR is the solution, i mean can't i use the same component and send them from client side?

Comment: You can use your client components with SSR if your components don't use the `WEB API` like the `window`. Just pass your application root to `renderToString` and try to run it, nodejs will tell you if you have troubles.

Comment: @SaveliTomac thanks again, i never used react ssr, could you please help me with some good module or any blog/link would be sufficient.

Comment: Of course, SSR is very simple. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring is a basics. https://alligator.io/react/react-router-ssr/ is a good article tells about ssr using `react-router`.

Comment: Also you can read article on medium about configuring webpack for ssr https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/adding-a-server-side-rendering-support-for-an-existing-react-application-using-express-and-webpack-5a3d60cf9762

Comment: @SaveliTomac thanks let me go through, and will disturb you again, if facing any issue :)

Comment: Of course, you can ask me here or svltmccc@icloud.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206691/discussion-between-parveen-yadav-and-saveli-tomac).

Answer (score 0):

Next js is the SSR for react apps may be you can look into it https://nextjs.org/

Comment: I don't think that rearrangement existing app to nextjs is simple task